# Check whether pattern is in csv field and output into a different file (whole row containing said pattern)

Tags: python, regex, list

I want to search through a csv file, a particular column (`Code`) for specific pattern(s).

For example

[image: Sample File]

I would like to use Python to extract rows 1 and 2 given they have the pattern `[0-9][0-9][A-Z]` in the column `Code`.

But the last row does not adhere to the above so I would like to negate it and output it into a different csv; and output the criteria that is satisfied onto a new csv.

Other patterns need to be included as well and may be present within the data so this is why I wanted to add it to a list variable and check the pattern that way. For instance a code critera could be `[0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][A-Z]`. Wonder if it would be best to go with perhaps regex however with a list I feel if there are additional patterns to include or required this can then be added to said list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering CSV rows by specific column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556643/filtering-csv-rows-by-specific-column-data) or is your question one about applying a regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without additional libraries then you could try:

```py
import csv
import re

patterns = ['[0-9][0-9][A-Z]', '[0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][A-Z]']
re_criteria = re.compile('(?:' + '|'.join(patterns) + ')$')

with open('data.csv', 'r') as fin,\
     open('satisfied.csv', 'w') as fout_1,\
     open('not_satisfied.csv', 'w') as fout_2:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    writer_1 = csv.DictWriter(fout_1, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer_2 = csv.DictWriter(fout_2, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer_1.writeheader()
    writer_2.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        if re_criteria.match(row['Code']):
            writer_1.writerow(row)
        else:
            writer_2.writerow(row)
```

Assumptions are: (1) the input file is named `data.csv`. (2) You want to match the `Code` items fully.

- First compile the `patterns` into a regex `re_criteria` by using an or concatenation `|`. The `$` at the end makes sure that the match is full. The non-capturing group `(?:...)` makes sure that `$` doesn't belong only to the last pattern in the list.
- Then use the `csv` module from the standard library to build a `reader` for the input file and 2 writers for the new output files (`satisfied.csv` for the rows that meet the criteria and `non_satisfied.csv` for those that don't). I'm using `csv.DictReader`/`Writer`s to access the `Code` column by name. (But this can easily be done by the "normal" `csv.reader`/`writer`s too.)
- Then iterate over the input rows and sort them according to the `Code` values matching the criteria or not.

If you decide to use Pandas, as @DavideAnghileri suggests, then I'd rather use Pandas `.str` methods (here `.str.fullmatch`) and do:

```py
import pandas as pd

patterns = ['[0-9][0-9][A-Z]', '[0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][A-Z]']

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
mask = df['Code'].str.fullmatch('|'.join(patterns))
df[mask].to_csv('satisfied.csv', index=False)
df[~mask].to_csv('not_satisfied.csv', index=False)
```

But, just to make sure, for the specific list of patterns in the question you could just use one pattern `[0-9][0-9][A-Z]( [0-9][0-9][A-Z])?$` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Timus, for the two different approaches. Can I ask what you mean by your 1st bullet point? re non-capturing group

Comment: @kdawg Thanks for the feedback! Regarding the _non-capturing group_: First, for your task at hand a _normal_ group `(...)` would work as well. A _normal_ group has a couple of features: (1) It allows to extract the sub-pattern inside it, e.g. `match[1]` would return the sub-match that corresponds to the 1. group. (2) It allows to refer to it later in the pattern, e.g. a `\1` in the pattern means that at this point a match expects the same as in the 1. group. (3) The same works in the `repl` argument of `re.sub`.

Comment: A _non-capturing_ group `(?:...)` doesn't have those features, it is used just to group a part of the pattern, for example to add quantifiers like `?`, `+`, `*` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

input_file = 'input.csv'
criteria_file = 'criteria.csv'
negated_file = 'negated.csv'
column_name = 'code'
patterns = ['[0-9][0-9][A-Z]', '[0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][A-Z]']

# Function to check if any of the patterns match the given value
def check_patterns(value):
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.match(pattern, value):
            return True
    return False

# Read the input CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)

# Filter rows based on patterns
criteria_df = df[df[column_name].apply(check_patterns)]
negated_df = df[~df[column_name].apply(check_patterns)]

# Write the filtered dataframes to CSV files
criteria_df.to_csv(criteria_file, index=False)
negated_df.to_csv(negated_file, index=False)
```

In this code, the input CSV file is read into a pandas DataFrame (df) using pd.read_csv().

The filtering is performed using the apply() method on the column_name column. The check_patterns() function is applied to each value in the column, and the resulting boolean series is used to filter the DataFrame.

Finally, the filtered DataFrames are written to separate CSV files using the to_csv() method.

Comment: @ Davide Anghileri thanks appreciate the response. Marked Timus as used it without Pandas library but appreciate your input too.